# sequelize js with big integers

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, bigint

I have an application written in Node JS and uses the Sequelize js ORM library to access my database which is MySql.

My problem is that I have a column in my db which is BIGINT and when the value of it is large I get wrong values when I retrieve it.

for example when the value in database is: `10205918797953057` I get `10205918797953056` when I get it using sequelize.

I tried using `big-integer` library but I had no luck.

any advice is welcomed.

P.S: I can't change the datatype to VARCHAR.

Comment: could it be `DataTypes.BIGINT` as [here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/datatypes/#bigint)

Comment: the column is defined in Mysql and in Sequelize as `BIGINT`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should enable `supportBigNumbers` and possibly `bigNumberStrings` on the mysql module: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-options

```
new Sequelize(..., {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectOptions: {
    supportBigNumbers: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate that saved the day.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Jan Aagaard Meier is correct and works, But there are few things to consider.

According to [Sequelize Docs (connection-options)](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options):

`supportBigNumbers`: When dealing with big numbers (BIGINT and DECIMAL columns) in the database, you should enable this option (Default: false).

`bigNumberStrings`: Enabling both `supportBigNumbers` and `bigNumberStrings` forces big numbers (BIGINT and DECIMAL columns) to be always returned as JavaScript String objects (Default: `false`). Enabling `supportBigNumbers` but leaving `bigNumberStrings` disabled will return big numbers as String objects only when they cannot be accurately represented with [JavaScript Number objects](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)(which happens when they exceed the [-2^53, +2^53] range), otherwise they will be returned as Number objects. This option is ignored if `supportBigNumbers` is disabled.

So, in some cases, to handle the returned value correctly, using both
`bigNumberStrings` and `supportBigNumbers` might be a better option
that **guarantees a string value in return**.